# How to get headers details in angularJs application to show username in page header

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angular web application running on node.

On page header I need to show logged in user id/name. I know user id, name is available in headers information but how can I access them in angular and show them in my `header.html`?

Comment: well i searched a lot but could find anything(code) which i can use in my application  except one but it is also not working..                            myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers ..   this header might have details but not sure how to use it i tried to print it in console but it shows nothing ... i may not be on the righ direction

Answer (score 0):

This information is in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> Returns a promise object with the standard then method and two http specific methods: success and error. The then method takes two arguments a success and an error callback which will be called with a response object. The success and error methods take a single argument - a function that will be called when the request succeeds or fails respectively. The arguments passed into these functions are destructured representation of the response object passed into the then method. The response object has these properties:
>
> **data** – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the
>   transform functions.
>
> **status** – {number} – HTTP status code of the
>   response.
>
> **headers** – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
>
> **config** – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate
>   the request.
>
> **statusText** – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

So, if you make a request, and the userID is supplied in the response headers, you can access it like this:

```
$http.get('someUrl')
    .success(function(data, status, headers) {
        $scope.userId = headers('userID');
    });
```

You may have to inspect your response headers to see exactly what header value need to access in order to get the user ID.

Then you add the binding to your html:

```
{{userId}}
```

Here is an example showing how to access $http response headers and display them in the view:

```
  $scope.headers;
  $scope.headerDate;
  $http.get('test.json')
  .success(function(data, status, headers) {
    $scope.headers = headers();
    $scope.headerDate = headers("Date");
  });
```

You can then display all response headers from that request by putting `{{headers}}` or just the date header with `{{headerDate}}`.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qpa9uZ2jJbZYr5UQR0wK?p=preview)

Comment: this doesnt work ..so far what i did is i got this value in my express server js.. here i m able to print it on console. now i m trying to  find a way as how to pass this varriab;e to my angular code...                                                                 app.get('/', function(req, res){
        var headerJson=JSON.stringify(req.headers, null, 2);
        console.log("Headers: " + headerJson);
        res.send("NODE app Headers: " + headerJson + "CorpID:" + JSON.parse(headerJson).host);
});

Comment: If your using node to pull the value from a get request header, angular already has the value. Post the function in node for your login authentication.  That's where node is passing angular a token. Your angular app also is storing that token somewhere, you can pull it from there without even messing with the headers.  Do you have a localStorage factory in your app?

Comment: See my updated answer for additional information.  It works; I think the issue may be that you aren't using it correctly.

In node you are pulling it from a get request which is coming from angular, which means angular is attaching the ID to the header in your app - which means angular already has it, so using node to try and get it again and send it back to angular is superfluous.